# Count Unique Text and value count

Tags: java, excel, vba

I would like to get the result unique count value/text/ etc

```
      A      B

2   BADER   111  
3   FAISA   112  
4   NASSE   113  
5   NASSE   113  
6   MOHS    121  
7   ASI     122  
8   AHME    100  
9   AHME    100  
10  AHME    100  
11  ASI     122
```

RESULT AS BELOW.

```
      A      B

2   BADER   111  
3   FAISA   112  
4   NASSE   113  
5   NASSE   113  
6   MOHS    121  
7   ASI     122  
8   AHME    100  
9   AHME    100  
10  AHME    100  
11  ASI     122
```

`6         6`

Comment: You should show us your effort. Additionally, the requirement is not clear (at least to me).

Comment: If `String` or `Integer` objects are added to a `Set<String>` or `Set<Integer>`, respectively, method `size()` of `Set` will tell you the number of unique entries.

Answer (score 0):

For the number of different values in A2:A11 try this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11<>"")/COUNTIF(A2:A11,A2:A11&""))`

That will work for numeric or text values